# Why does Eclipse content assist fail to generate a method stub from a partial method name?

Tags: java, eclipse

Previously, I've been able to create a method stub in Eclipse (Java) by typing the method name and pressing CTRL - SPACE. This would then give me the option of automatically generating a void method stub.

Unfortunately, recently I've been unable to do this for any method name longer than two characters. Once the word is longer than 2 chars, the option is no longer there.

I've looked at the templates in the options, and found the private_method and public_method templates, which are similar, but not quite right. The void method stub is nowhere in there. Also, the icon next to the void method stub is different to the templates, which leads me to believe that it is indeed something other than templates.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of why this isn't working for anything longer than two characters?

Here's an image of the code suggestion I'm looking for (the selected one):

[image]

EDIT: For clarification, I've added two more images showing the problem, and a further description:

In the case where there are two characters and I press CTRL - SPACE, I get the autocomplete option for creating the method stub (which is what I want). However, when pressing CTRL - SPACE with more than two characters before the cursor, there is no such suggestion. See the second image below and you'll see what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think we need to see more, like the class declaration itself, and what should be proposed but is not.

Comment: Okay, here's two further images that show my problem. In the case where there are two characters and I press CTRL - SPACE, I get the autocomplete option for creating the method stub (which is what I want).

However, when pressing CTRL - SPACE with more than two characters before the cursor, there is no such suggestion. See the second image below and you'll see what I mean.

https://imgur.com/OLzLG8K,TLEEMgF#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to [Code Recommenders](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/), which is now enabled by default in Eclipse (as of the Mars release, I think). To me it looks like a bug, either behavioral or, if it's working as intended, it's a usability and/or UI bug, because it's difficult to understand the new behavior.

One workaround is to disable Code Recommenders for code completion; see this screen shot for where to do so in the **Preferences**.

[image]

If you want to keep Code Recommenders enabled (it does seem to provide some valuable functionality), is to tweak a particular setting so that the method template is included for more characters. I'm not exactly sure how or why it's related to what you're seeing, but it does seem to work. I'm also not sure of the performance impact of adjusting this too much, as indicated by the UI instructions.

[image]
Increasing the "Maximum prefix length" for the sub-words completion seems to allow larger numbers of characters to trigger the method template suggestion. Again, I'm not sure why but I strongly suspect it's a bug in Code Recommenders.

I suggest asking about it on their forum and/or entering a bug about this: https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/community/

Comment: This solved the issue for me, and I've gone with the option of increasing the minimum prefix length. I'll head over to their forum and see if I can get any more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

form the image I can tell that you are trying to write your code within the class block and not within a method block...

```
Example 
class a {
// you are trying to write your code here
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I am writing in the class block. I want to add a method to the class, so that's to be expected. As you can see from my edit and the link I posted, the autocomplete works fine there, as long as the text before the cursor isn't longer than two characters.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed with Eclipse Code Recommenders 2.2.5.
You can download it from the Recommenders stable update site stable [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/recommenders/updates/stable/).